# Databricks autoloader checkpoint data read

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, delta-lake

In Databricks auto loader, How to read the data inside the checkpoint directory and understand For each batch how what are all the files it processed ?. I Know we can use cloud_file_state() but it's not providing all the information And in case of delta table as source how we can identify what is the latest version of the delta table we processed?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula yes